# CORS filter does not apply for spring oauth/token

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have the following configuration for my filter. `OPTIONS` request does not seem to get through when making CORS request to `localhost:8080/oauth/token`.

```
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); // @Value: http://localhost:8080
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(-1);
    return bean;
  }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();
}
```

Did i miss something in my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was with the order of the filter should have been setlike this :

```
   bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
```